# MATLAB - Line Objects

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

2 questions about Matlab's Line:

1. Is it possible to store a line object without adding a figure? I'd like to run a script that creates approximately 8,000 lines, and I'd love not to have them all pop up on a figure.
2. If I have a Line stored (in the workspace I have a variable called myLine, with a value of 1x1 Line), how do I plot it with all of its properties?

Thanks!

My workspace is telling me that it isn't a cell, it isn't a struct, it isn't an array. It is a Line. I am wondering what this means.

Comment: your *line* is a simple array of 1x2 size ?

Comment: I'm looking at my workspace tab. It says: myLine 1x1 Line

Comment: ??? I don't get you ... is it a cell or 1x1 array ?

Comment: It seems to display like a struct object would, but it is of type Line

Comment: Why do you want a line-object but no plot for it? If you want to just store the line for further use, define an own format.

Comment: there is no need to use cells, just an array ... is sufficient to your needs. IMHO

Comment: It looks like the line objects are existent only in a context of axis. So the answer to (1) seems to be "no" and (2) doesn't have meaning as the line stored is not a line, but a handle to a line already on the plot.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. You are correct! That makes sense. Once I closed the figure the object was deleted. Makes sense to me.

Comment: So we are back at creating your own format... Just store the two points and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a figure object if you want to create a line object, but you don't have to display the figure in order to manipulate it, save it to disk, etc. For example,

---

```
n = 2 ;
T = 100 ;
x = cumsum(randn(T,2)) ;

fh = figure('Visible','off') ;
for ii = 1:n
    clf() ;
    ax = axes('Parent',fh) ;
    lh = plot(ax,x(:,ii)) ;
    saveas(fh,sprintf('myplot%g.fig',ii)) ;
end
```

Obviously if you want to keep all of the line objects in memory then you need to create figure objects for all of them. This is a trivial modification of the example above.